# Should I use ReleaseStringUTFChars if I want to return the C sting obtained from GetStringUTFChars?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
jstring result = NULL;
**const char *nativeString = NULL;**

if (messageMe != NULL) {
    jstring jstrBuf = (envLocal)->NewStringUTF(value);
    result = (jstring) envLocal->CallStaticObjectMethod(g_clazz, messageMe,
            jstrBuf);
    **nativeString = envLocal->GetStringUTFChars(result, 0);**
    g_JavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
    return nativeString;
```

Hi as shown in above example code I am filling nativeString using GetStringUTFChars. my need is to return this nativeString to call to another native calling function.

Must I use ReleaseStringUTFChars(). If I use it then won't it free the memory and nativeString value for the calling function will be invalid.???

I am not getting this answer clearly in other stack overflow questions. please help.

Comment: Yes, you must release the buffer. The easiest way to deal with this is to return an std::string instead of char*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetStringUTFChars` will allocate memory for the string it returns, and `ReleaseStringUTFChars` frees that memory. So you should call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` when you're done using the data that `GetStringUTFChars` returned.

Comment: yes but, there is a problem because I am returning the data to calling function. I am not done in this implemented function.

Comment: char * getSomeString(JNIEnv *env, jstring jstr) {
   char * retString;
   char * intermedString;

   intermedString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, NULL);
   retString = strdup(intermedString);
   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr, intermedString);
   return retString;
}

Comment: did you mean like that Michael. but, in that case retString is still allocated inside the function. how it will be freed?

Comment: Whoever uses it last will have to free it.